# sails-auth not generating models, policies etc.,

Tags: npm, sails.js

I installed a fresh sails application, I planned to integrate passport for authentication. Sails-auth seems to be the easiest way but it just doesn't create any files as said in the doc..

sails : 0.12.14

I got this deprecated warning while installing sails-auth though,

```
newmacs-iMac:dn dev$ npm install sails-auth --save  
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
```

Comment: it doesn't seems to work anymore with latest sails...I am going with sails-hook-passport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow the steps explained on https://github.com/trailsjs/sails-auth

First, do `npm install sails-auth --save` followed by installing a password strategy you want to use, e.g. `npm install passport-google-oauth`
Then create the file `config/passport.js` with the following content according to the passport strategy you want to use, for example:

```
module.exports.passport = {
  local: {
    strategy: require('passport-local').Strategy
  },

  basic: {
    strategy: require('passport-http').BasicStrategy,
    protocol: 'basic'
  }
};
```

More examples can be found here https://github.com/trailsjs/sails-auth/blob/master/config/passport.js

Then create `config/auth.js`

```
bcrypt: {
    /**
     * Specifiy number of salt rounds to perform on password. Values >10 are
     * slow.
     */
    rounds: 8
  }
```

Then you are ready to authenticate to `/auth/local` or `/auth/google` depending on the passport strategy you are using.

**Important:** with sails v1.0 `sails-auth` does no longer seem to work but since you are using sails 0.12 it should work.